# Best way to find out which php file has generated an html line of code in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

Using Chrome you can right click - Inspect element to see the html code behind that element:

[image: Chrome inspect element example]

I wonder how to find which php file has generated that html. Maybe there is some tool to put a breakpoint into the html so the php server will stop when trying to generate it again?

I'm using WordPress locally. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04LMS. I'm using Sublime Text 3 with XDebug.

---

**UPDATE 1**

A WordPress plugin able to put, in every file, something like the following would be a good solution (I think from my beginner's viewpoint):

```
echo '<!-- name_of_the_php_file.php -->';
```

Comment: When inspecting an element with chrome (or other) developer tools, it might not be part of the actual html. It might also come from javascript

Comment: In your sublime text editor use command+shift+f to find in all file i Yo Quiero!. i am sure it work fine

Comment: @amitrh, WordPress usually stores that kind of text in the database, not the php file

Comment: What about trying to find the source files of someone _else's_ website?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this plugin "[what the file](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/)" to find out the php file. Then rest it is to find out a function or something else by CTRL + F in any editor.

I want to add one more plugin which is not exactly for this purpose but it is very popular among WordPress developers and it solves this problem very well. The plugin is [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).

Comment: This plugin worked perfectly. An actually time saver. Thank you and welcome to stackoverflow Rituparna Sonowal!

Comment: Wow massive help thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Put an echo in your PHP pages to print their name in an HTML comment based on whether a session variable is set. Then set that session variable and enjoy.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['printPageName']) && $_SESSION['printPageName']=='true')
{
   echo '<!-- ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ' -->';
}
```

The reason I say to use a session variable is so you can create some mechanism to where you can occasionally look at this for debug purposes, but users don't normally encounter it.

Comment: I put it in the _header.html_ of the theme. Unfortunately, the output says: `<!-- /websiteurl/index.php -->`. _index.php_ has the following line of code: `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will be the file actually being called by the user. So in that case I guess you'd  have to hardcode the name in header.php `echo '<!-- header.php -->';` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice solution. Actually it would be nice a WordPress plugin to add that code at the beginning of every php file. Not a task for me (yet, as I'm starting with WordPress). Maybe in the future if there is not anything already done. Actually, I'll keep this question open a couple of days to motivate other solutions okay? Thank you!

Comment: You could always just put in `<?php echo "<!-- ".__FILE__."-->"; ?>` on all your template files

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately with wordpress you need to do some digging:

1. Is it a page/ post / custom post (i.e. you can find the page in the admin section and edit it)
2. If yes - look at the template assigned (posts don't usually have a template select field unless custom code added) and find the matching page template in your theme (page-whatever.php)(it might not be called what you see in the dropdown field, but in its notes it will have the name you see), or if a post you are looking for single.php or if custom post look for single-whatever.php.
3. The above is default and will cover 60% of situations. But if you add a plugin and it adds new pages, the page template will be in the plugin and the real fun starts.
4. If a plugin is developed with user mods in mind, it should have its pages in 1 location or in a functional set folder. Have a look for the above files in these locations if they exist or in the general plugin folders.
5. If still no luck, have a look for `add_action('save_post', 'whatever');` there may be code stating `return $template` , this will prob also have the post type in the function. Look for the path its calling
6. Another way to add a page is through a url rewrite (search through the files for rewrite). It will contain a path somewhere to the file (there are a couple of methods of doing this so look them up so you will recognise them).

If you think you have found the correct template, try a echo to see if it appears on screen. If yes you have found the template, look at what you have follow the includes/ requires to appropiate .php files, you'll find your html somewhere either as html or php code creating html.

### hopefully you find what you are looking for, but there are no rules really and other methods can exist including htaccess rewrites to point to php file, etc or a functions file creating pages on the fly

This might be a good point to mention if you ever create a entire plugin, store files logically and include from a file controller or plugin file. Store pages in a pages folder so they are easy to find.

Good luck!

update: filter to output path on template files

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'show_path', 99 );

function show_path( $template ) {

            if($template):
                echo $template;
            else:
                echo "template path not found";
            endif;

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: well, a plugin to add the piece of code that @developerwjk has suggested in every php file would solve this common "problem". What do you think?

Comment: hmm you could open every file and write it in with php i suppose, or do it manually, but honestly what i do is the above, i will find template files fairly quickly and then follow require/includes. You dont need a plugin for what he suggests, just use this filter to spit out the path http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include  again, this only works for pages/posts within db, it will fail for rewrites, etc and rewrites are used a lot for pages like payments pages, logins, etc.

Comment: wow wow that plugin seems a nice (though as you said partial) solution. I don't know how to use it at all. I think I should create a new plugin with that example code, right? Then within the `function portfolio_page_template`, using the function [single_tag_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_tag_title) somehow. Is it what you mean? (I'm beginning to touch the source code of WordPress)

Comment: i updated a filter to try. Put it in your theme function files or plugin file, etc

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that piece of code. I put it within the index.php of the theme with no change. How to use it? Should I create a new public with that exact piece of code inside. Sorry I'm just starting with WordPress!

Comment: put it in your functions file in your active theme. (look for functions.php)

Comment: I put the full piece of code after the last function of _functions.php_. The web application does not load after it. `add_filter( 'template_include', 'show_path', 99 );` is executed, but `function show_path( $template ) {}` is never called.

Comment: what do you mean by application does not load? white page or loads header and no content? It sounds like a php error but you have errors off. Theres no errors in the code above (i think :)) but there may be a error with locate template, comment out all this code and just `echo $template` and see what it outputs, it should output a filename

Comment: If I put the code after the last function (but inside the class Theme), the result is a white page (there is no any html code generated). If I put the code outside the `class Theme`, the result of the piece of code is _template path not found_, whereas the result of `echo $template` is empty.

Comment: well you cant put it in a class without mods. This may be one of these cases where this function is not suitable (did you check on a page where it uses a template?) is it a post or a page without a db entry by any chance?

Comment: oh sorry man, I can't understand you well. I guess it because I'm beginning with PHP and WordPress!

Comment: ok updated it there it should be working. Php OOP classes have a different syntax and you add_actions + filters using `array(&this, 'functionname')` but dont worry about that for now!

Answer (score 2):

Hope to find this plugin useful. use to search in files amd wasting enough time. Also i use **What the file** plugin as suggested before, it is a great way. But i think combining the String Locator this will have extra fun!  [String Locator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing and welcome to stackoverflow! :)

Comment: I didn't find about the plugin here, but after 4 hours looking for a link to change the href, I found about String Locator plugin. And I had to thank it somewhere, since I'm not registered in wordpress.org, I thought I'd upvote and leave a Thank You in stackoverflow.
Don't waste any more time looking for hidden code

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to copy an id or class from the html. Then search that string through the source code of the WordPress web application to put a breakpoint at every place where the string appears.

However, the string could be in the database. In that case, this method won't work.

Answer (score 1):

> First tack a backup of whole websiter, suppose /my-website
>
> 1.Right click on element for that you want to find php code
>   2.Cope CLASS or ID selector of that line
>   3.Search that CLASS or ID selector in editor inside /my-website folder, for this notepad++ and Dreamweaver editor is best.

Answer (score 1):

Start page code

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
```

HTML content

```
...
...

<sapan>Original text</span>

....
...
```

end page code.

```
<?php
/*    get and delete current buffer      &&  start a new buffer */
if ((($html = ob_get_clean()) !== false) && (ob_start() === true))
{
    echo preg_replace('~<sapan>Original text</span>~i', '<!-- name_of_the_php_file.php -->', $html, 1);
}
?>
```

Note: Sory, my English not good.

Answer (score 1):

Not all data is stored in html or php files in Wordpress.

It may be possible that the string you are looking for is coming from database since wordpress uses database to store variable data.

**Please search database also**