# Xdebug in Sublime Text 3: how to put a dynamic breakpoint when any file within a folder is called

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimetext3, xdebug

I'm trying to find out when a WordPress plugin is executed (this one: /wp-content/plugins/goodlayers-lms/*). I have put a breakpoint in the first index.php of WordPress, but it is being surprisingly slow to reach some file within the plugin by hand (pushing Ctrl+Shift+f7 to step into everything, then seeing if some file within the plugin is opened).

Is it possible to do it with Xdebug or Sublime? Any other idea?

---

**UPDATE 1**

After more than one hour keeping pushed Ctrl+Shift+f7, the debugger not only reach the end, but also Ubuntu crashed. My suggestion of starting with a breakpoint in index.php was not the winner strategy xD

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a manual `xdebug_break()` call in your code where you want to break.

Comment: A normal breakpoint would  also work. I would have to put a breakpoint (or `xdebug_break()`) in every file within the plugin though!

Comment: The plugin I suggest in the UPDATE 1 of the following question would work too for this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451369/best-way-to-find-out-which-php-file-has-generated-an-html-line

Comment: My opinion is that XDebug isn't really the right tool for tracking down HTML / template snippets, searching through your code using a tool like grep or ag might have better results.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, those tools are for searching a string. How can I know which part of the plugin is executed when I pushed a button in the website?

Comment: You're not wrong. I'd say at some point you just need to develop an understanding about how your application works in order to make educated guesses about where a particular piece of functionality may be implemented. That said, your two general strategies for figuring this out would be tracing the logic through from the front end (controller / index) side, or identify what output you're getting and (using text searching, etc) identify where in the code that output is being generated. As you found though, tracing a very large application step by step is rarely effective.

Comment: Anyway, Sublime Text has a nice built-in search within files system. We just need to push Ctrl+Shift+f or right click on a folder and search.

Comment: BTW, I'm also trying to do what you suggest... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451369/best-way-to-find-out-which-php-file-has-generated-an-html-line

Answer (score 0):

I suggest install superior editor [phpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). It have builtin many cool stuff like your mentioned breakpoints. As well it have Wordpress integration.

Comment: I have installed it. How could I tell PHPStorm to stop (and set a breakpoint) everytime any file within _/wp-content/plugins/goodlayers-lms/_ is called?