# How to find out from which PHP file code is coming from inspecting the code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing WordPress website in that if we want to know buttons PHP coding is coming from which PHP file, is there any shortcut from which we can find it out easily? Like by doing inspect we can know which CSS file is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to find out which php file has generated an html line of code in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451369/best-way-to-find-out-which-php-file-has-generated-an-html-line-of-code-in-wordpr)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make use of the text search functionalities of any of the editor, If yo are using eclipse cntrl + H will give you the text search utility.
2. If you are in linux environement, use grep command to search the button text or class name.

In wordpress you can see the file, /wp-admin/includes/template.php the button functions are defined in this file.