# How to remove a part of an html code inside of a php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, storefront, child-theming

I was trying to remove a "Search" button on the top left corner of a web site.

After searching here I found a tip here: [Best way to find out which php file has generated an html line of code in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451369/best-way-to-find-out-which-php-file-has-generated-an-html-line-of-code-in-wordpr)

But still after installing the plugin I could not be able to locate the desired html line to simply erase it. Also tried using the css code above to temporary hide it.

```
.pesquisar {
display: none !important;
}
```

It did not work. Can somebody help me on how can I erase `<button type="submit" value="Pesquisar">Pesquisar</button>` from the html code?

Comment: If you have full control of your codebase have you tried searching your entire codebase for it? Even if it's being generated by a script the string literals would be in code unless it is being pulled in from an external source.

Comment: Many thanks I managed to find a solution using a string locator plugin, I have shared the solution in an comment, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a great solution.

To anyone in need to find a specific part of an html code there is a plugin called String Locator: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/

It allows you to find across any file and regex. Ideally the plugin allows editing after identifying the file, but because I was using security plugins I got an error.

Desipte that the path of the located file is shown, so I was able to manually get to the located file and change it.

Another tip is if your file identified with the string plugin is located in a cache folder like it was in my case I recommend cleaning the cache using plugins such as autoptimize or wp fastest cache then do the search again.

When I did there was only one file that remains needing an edit, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css `style= "display:none;"` rule

```
<button type="submit" value="Pesquisar" style="display:none;">Pesquisar</button>
```

If you cannot find who generates this, maybe it's caused a wp plugin generates that content. Try to locate first who generates the button.

Comment: You do see that  the OP has that code in his CSS, no?

Comment: As I understand it, he doesn't know where the HTML element is actually being generated, so he doesn't have 'access' to it.

Comment: Many thanks I managed to find a solution using a string locator plugin, I have shared the solution in an comment, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class "pesquisar" to the button, then your CSS will work:

```
<button class="pesquisar" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">Pesquisar</button>
```

In your CSS you use a class selector:

```
.pesquisar { // selects the items with class="pesquisar"
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks I managed to find a solution using a string locator plugin, I have shared the solution in an comment, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to hide it:

```
button[value="pesquisar"]{
      display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks I managed to find a solution using a string locator plugin, I have shared the solution in an comment, many thanks.